# Bootstrap modal won't close when clicking "x" or "close" buttons

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

The modal shows up just fine when clicking it to open, and the close buttons register that my mouse is hovering over them, but when clicked nothing happens and the modal remains open.
Has anyone encountered/fixed this problem before? All I've seen on here is to add "data-bs-dismiss" but that hasn't made a difference in the modal. I'm new to bootstrap so any and all help would be much appreciated! Code is below, link to full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsnraetff/L2n0dbo1/4/)  -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name= "viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Pokedex</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="./CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/scripts.js" defer></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    

    <div class="pokedex">
      <h1 class="pokemon-header">Pokedex</h1>
      <ul class="pokemon-list list-group"></ul></div>
      
      <div class="modal" id="modal-container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-container" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h2 class="modal-title"></h2>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
      <script src="js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
      <script src="js/fetch-polyfill.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: No errors show up on console

Comment: In order to troubleshoot we'll need to be able to see the page and since this code references relative assets (js/scripts.js, css/styles.css, etc) we can't see it. Please post with absolute paths or JS fiddle, etc.

But if it's not a JS error then probably the script isn't running due to the way it's being [bubbled/captured](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Comment: Here is a link to the JSfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mdsnraetff/L2n0dbo1/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues.

Let's start with the way the orange poke-buttons are created.

```
function addListItem(pokemon) {
    let listItem = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');
    let button = $('<button class="pokemon-button btn btn-warning" data target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">' + pokemon.name + '</button>');
    listItem.append(button);
    pokemonListElement.append(listItem);
    button.on('click', function(){
      showDetails(pokemon);
    });
  }
```

This seems to be fine... But:

```
let button = $('<button class="pokemon-button btn btn-warning" data target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">' + pokemon.name + '</button>');
```

Take a look at `data target="#modal-container` . There's a hyphen missing, and instead of this

```
data target="#modal-container"
```

it should look like this:

```
data-target="#modal-container"
```

Next, there's no need to have this line in your `showDetailsModal(pokemon)` function:

```
modalContainer.classList.add('show');
```

The `data-target` and `data-toggle` will cover that part for you.

Finally, your CSS seems to be putting the modal's backdrop on top of the modal. Change this:

```
#modal-container {
    ...
    z-index: 999;
    ...
}
```

to something else (for example, 1051, or you can delete it, and let Bootstrap handle it for you), since the backdrop has a `z-index` of 1040.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the behavior in the JSFiddle by replacing the following two lines in the showDetailsModal function:

```
let modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
```

with this line:

```
$('#modal-container').modal('show');
```

that is one of the methods provided in Bootstrap 4.3 per:
[the Bootstrap Modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#modalshow)

Also, it's necessary to add the `data-backdrop="false"` attribute to your `modal-container` div in order to maintain the current style/behavior.

This may not be the best solution - I am not sure why your code doesn't work, it seems reasonable to me, but I think it's a good idea to use the default methods provided by the library as other methods (like the close function) may be expecting them and fail to work if you're using an improvised method.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help! Looks like this in combo with the previous comment did the trick